# How to pass $scope variables into the Node.js server using $resource

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have $scope.todos and in my controller the code for submitting that is

```
$scope.submitChanges = function() {
    var todos = $resource("/todo");

    //code goes here for sending variable
}
```

And I want to send it to Node.js , which takes it as  :

```
router.post("/",function(req, res) {
    var collection = db.get("todo");
    collection.insert({ /* here comes the data to insert */ }, function(err, todos) {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.json(todos);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var CreditCard = $resource('/todos/:Id',
 {userId:123, Id:'@id'}, {
 charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
});
```

Comment: sorry no clue about express